# How to run multiple modules separately in multi-module maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a multi-module maven project and each module is spring boot application. I want to run each module under parent project.

For example:

`Parent P
    -- module A
        -- src
        -- pom.xml
    -- module B
        --src
        --pom.xml
    --pom.xml`

What i am doing now is executing mvn clean install from parent pom on command prompt and then navigating to target folder of each module and executing each jar with java - jar

I want to run module A first and then module B in a single shot. Is this possible? How to do it in maven.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that come to mind to achieve what you want to do:

### Script

Write a script that builds and starts each module.  I've included a Windows batch script as an example.

**maven.bat**

```
mvn clean package
start java -jar module-a/target/module-a-0.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
start java -jar module-b/target/module-b-0.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

### [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/)

Use Docker and more specifically, [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) to start up all your modules with a single command:

```
docker-compose up
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
modulea:
 image: foobar/modulea
 ports:
  - "8080:8080"
 links:
  - moduleb
 environment:
  - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
moduleb:
 image: foobar/moduleb
 ports:
  - "8081:8080"
 links:
  - modulea
 environment:
  - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
```

Visit the links to the documentation for more detail on how to use Docker & docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

From `Parent P`, you could achieve what you want using a single inline command (I splitted it in two lines just for reading purposes):

```
nohup mvn spring-boot:run -pl module-A -Dserver.port=8090 &
nohup mvn spring-boot:run -pl module-B -Dserver.port=8091 &
```

The command(s) presented above allows one to run both Spring Boot application modules in the background, each on its dedicated port.

The output of the [nohup](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) command, i.e. the Spring Boot startup log, will be sent to `nohup.out`, placed on the `Parent P` directory.